# How can I compute the duration of events splited in different rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, gps

I am working on a dataframe with processed gps positions. I have three variables: `id`, that correponds to the identifier of every individual, `TimeStamp`, that indicates the moment of the gps signal, and `perimeter` that indicates whether the signal occurred within a given perimeter. I would like to create a table with the time spent within or out of the given perimeters in the correct order of occurrences.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1, 10),
                 TimeStamp=seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 12:00:00"), 
                               as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 16:30:00"), 
                               length.out = 10),
                 perimeter=c(NA, NA, NA, "p1", "p1", "p1", NA, NA, "p2", "p2"))
```

And my desired output would be like this:

```
id perimeter time
1  NA        1.5
1  "p1"      1.5
1  NA        1
1  "p2"      1
```

I have approached a solution using the `rle()` function:

```
df[is.na(df$perimeter),]$perimeter <- "OUT"

data.frame(perimeter=rle(df$perimeter)$value,
           time=(rle(df$perimeter)$length*30)/60)
```

However, it performs an estimation of the time given the length of a sequence of duplicates within the vector, and as I have missing values, subtracting the TimeStamp of the first duplicates from the last one would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dplyr solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(perimeter = forcats::fct_explicit_na(df$perimeter),
         visit = cumsum(perimeter != lag(perimeter) | is.na(lag(perimeter)))) %>% 
  group_by(id, visit, perimeter) %>% 
  summarise(time = difftime(max(TimeStamp) + 1800, min(TimeStamp), unit = "hour")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-visit)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id perimeter time     
#>   <dbl> <fct>     <drtn>   
#> 1     1 (Missing) 1.5 hours
#> 2     1 p1        1.5 hours
#> 3     1 (Missing) 1.0 hours
#> 4     1 p2        1.0 hours
```

Comment: Thanks, by shifting the order of the variables in the group_by() function and by adding half an hour to the max(TimeStamp) I get exactly my desired output.
```df %>% 
  mutate(perimeter = forcats::fct_explicit_na(df$perimeter),
         visit = cumsum(perimeter != lag(perimeter) | is.na(lag(perimeter)))) %>% 
  group_by(id, visit, perimeter) %>% 
  summarise(time = difftime(max(TimeStamp)+1800, min(TimeStamp), unit = "hour")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-visit)
```

Comment: @Antoine. I have made the changes so this matches your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, nextTimeStamp := shift(TimeStamp, -1L), by = id]
df[, .( unclass(nextTimeStamp[.N] - TimeStamp[1L]) / 60^2), by = .(id, rleid(perimeter))]

#    id rleid  V1
# 1:  1     1 1.5
# 2:  1     2 1.5
# 3:  1     3 1.0
# 4:  1     4  NA
```